# Error compiling dynamicly C#, after reboot machine work ok

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, csc

I create some method(this is only test method, to isolate problem from very very big system):

```
private void CompileHalloWorld()
{
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((30000));

  if (!Directory.Exists(_workingDir))
  {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(_workingDir);
  }
  Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(_workingDir);

  var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
  var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "foo.exe", true);
  parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
  CompilerResults results = null;
  try
  {
    results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
      @"using System;
        class Program {
          public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(""Hallo World!"");
          }
        }");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    int a = 2;
  }
  results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
}
```

On 99% machines this method work good, but on one of machines is some issue. When server work some times (few days), something broke in Windows I think. Then, when I run CompileHalloWorld() from exe app all work fine, but when I run this method from simple empty service, after invoke CompileAssemblyFromSourceinvoke in results structure is no errors in collection, but csc.exe return exit code -1073741502... After reboot of server all work good again, but I can't restart server every day...

I try to find some solution in SO. I check in Task Manager and no csc.exe proces hang, no Visual Studio work, no VBCSCompiler.exe hangs...

Please help me.

Comment: Format this machine - if this doesn't help some of your components are broken. Probably CPU, maybe RAM.

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak if _"CPU"_ or _"RAM"_ was the issue Windows would know about it first, not a User-mode application.  A p-code one at that.  OP did not mentioned any BSOD

Comment: @Tomasz Sorry, you want to format production server ?This is not possible.

Comment: You have a cluster of machines with backup in place for production and one machine down would only mean a drop in performance? Right? You can boot this on a new machine and swap them in place, but this is not https://serverfault.com/ for such advice.

Comment: `-1073741502` is error code `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED`. Maybe that gives you enough information to start diagnosing the issue.

Comment: @IInspectable great! Can you link some error codes table with messages?

Comment: Those symbolic constants are scattered across many, many files in the Windows SDK. I usually just go to magnumdb.com and see if anything of value comes up. If a 32-bit value is negative when interpreted as a signed quantity it's pretty safe to assume an `HRESULT` or `NT_STATUS` code.